# Help with table finish cracking

Tags: wood, polyurethane, finish

We have an alder table that is about 10 years old. We just noticed some cracking in the finish as you can see on the pictures. We are trying to figure out what to do to stop more from forming and what we can do to fix it. I am assuming that this is a polyurethane finish.

[image: wood table with crackling finish]

[image: wood table close up]

Searching the web for this came up with very little except perhaps alligatoring finish though the picture of that looks different.

Comment: Without knowing what the finish is my only suggestion is a refinish. Actually, it would be even if I _did_ know what that is. There's no repairing this finish.

Comment: You might be able to use lacquer thinner to partially dissolve the current finish to fix it, but I'm with isherwood, I would refinish it.